# Not able to get javascript running when used with ascx control

Tags: javascript, ascx

I am using java script in one of my web pages.

I have a ascx control, where the controls are added and this ascx control is added to an existing page in our application.

when I am expecting the java script method to be invoked, there is an error as

---

### Error

A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?

Line: 1827

### Error: Object expected

### Yes   No

and I don't see the mentioned line number while trying to debug.

The same piece of code works well, when it is added to a aspx page.
Is there any thing different when we use it with ascx control?

Answer (score 0):

Server side controls can't be added using javascript or jquery, Use litral control.